# How to call html view part to the controller from another page using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I need one help.i need to open one pop up window whose code is present inside the my `deal.php` page.I need to open by declaring the directive inside my controller function.Let me to explain my code below.

> deal.php:

```
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="productdata">Add Product Stock</a></li>

<div class="container">
          <!-- Chats, File upload and Recent Comments -->
          <!--1st Chat window -->
          <div class="row"   ui-view>

          </div>
          <!-- End 1st chat window -->
        </div>

    <modal title="Specification" visible="showSpecification">
      <textarea id="spec" class="form-control" ng-model="specification_modal" rows="7" style="width:100%;"></textarea>
      </modal>
```

When user clicked on `Add Product Stock` it will move to the below path.

```
.state('productdata',{
        url:'/data',
        templateUrl:'productview/productData.html',
        controller:'productDataController'
    })
```

> productData.html:

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Product Name :</span>
<select class="form-control"  id="product_name" ng-model="product_name" ng-options="cat.name for cat in listOfProduct track by cat.value " ng-change="removeBorder('product_name');">
</select>
</div>
```

Here i need when i wiil select the product name from the list the modal pop up window should open.

productDataController.js:

```
var productData=angular.module('medilink');
productData.controller('productDataController',function($scope,$http,$state,$window,$filter,Upload,productInpuFieldFocus){
   $scope.removeBorder=function(id){
}
})
productData.directive('modal', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div class="modal fade">' + 
          '<div class="modal-dialog">' + 
            '<div class="modal-content">' + 
              '<div class="modal-header">' + 
                '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + 
                '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' + 
              '</div>' + 
              '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' + 
            '</div>' + 
          '</div>' + 
        '</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      replace:true,
      scope:true,
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.title = attrs.title;

        scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
          if(value == true)
            $(element).modal('show');
          else
            $(element).modal('hide');
        });

        $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
          });
        });

        $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
            scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Here my requirement is when user will select the value from drop down the pop up window will open and the value should display in text area of the pop up window.Please help me.

Comment: What is the issue that you're facing with your current code ?

Comment: @Arkantos : i have tried put the modal part inside `ui- view`but the modal is coming but its becoming disabled.